# How can I Open a new activity by using a dialog box in android

Tags: android

I am not able to use the startActivity() function in my class and now I am stuck. But I have to open a new activity from this class. Please help me...

Here is my class and I want to open a new activity by using the onClick event in this class which is defined below

```
package com.fva_001.flashvsarrow.com.fva_001;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.*;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MapFoundDialog extends Dialog implements android.view.View.OnClickListener {

public Activity c;
public Dialog d;
public Button yes;

public MapFoundDialog(Activity a) {
    super(a);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.c = a;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
    setContentView(R.layout.dialog_map_found);
    yes = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_hide_dialog_map_found);
    yes.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    new ButtonClick(getContext(), v);
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_map_open:
            // i want to open a new activity from here....

            break;
        case R.id.btn_hide_dialog_map_found:
            dismiss();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    dismiss();
}
}
```

Comment: are you sure this case is being executed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I would not suggest passing the Activity to the dialog, since it may cause Activity Leak, and that's serious performance issue!

Why u pass activity to the dialog? You can pass ApplicationContext.

Use this code:

```
public class MapFoundDialog extends Dialog implements android.view.View.OnClickListener {

public Context c;
public Dialog d;
public Button yes;

public MapFoundDialog(Context c) {
    super(c);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.c = c.getApplicationContext();
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
    setContentView(R.layout.dialog_map_found);
    yes = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_hide_dialog_map_found);
    yes.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    new ButtonClick(c, v);
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_map_open:
            // i want to open a new activity from here....
             Intent intent = new Intent(c, NewActivity.class);
             c.startActivity(intent);
             break;

        case R.id.btn_hide_dialog_map_found:
            dismiss();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    dismiss();
}
}
```